# My JasperReport is not creating the report, just a blank page

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to create a JasperReport with Spring Boot. My endpoint gives me back some byte[] but it's just blank... I don't know what am I doing wrong.

```
     try{            
        Map<String, Object> extractParams = new HashMap<>();

        Marina marina = marinaProvider.findById(marinaId);
        MovementPlan movementPlan = this.getMovementPlanById(movementPlanId, marinaId);

        extractParams.put("MARINA_NAME", marina.getTradeName());
        extractParams.put("MARINA_CNPJ", marina.getCompanyFederalId());
        extractParams.put("BOAT_NAME", movementPlan.getBoat().getName());
        extractParams.put("BOAT_TYPE", movementPlan.getBoat().getBowType());
        extractParams.put("BOAT_MODEL", movementPlan.getBoat().getModelYear());
        extractParams.put("BOAT_TIE", movementPlan.getBoat().getTie());
        extractParams.put("RESPONSABLE", movementPlan.getNavigationPlan().getResponsible().getName());
        extractParams.put("CONTACT_RESPONSABLE", movementPlan.getNavigationPlan().getResponsible().getEmergencyContact());
        extractParams.put("SAILOR", "Sem marinheiro");
        extractParams.put("CONTACT_SAILOR", "000-0000");
        extractParams.put("VACANCY", movementPlan.getBoat().getVacancy().getCode());
        extractParams.put("OUTPUT_EXPECTATION", movementPlan.getCurrentMovement().getMovementPlan().getId());


        extractParams.put("REPORT_LOCALE", new Locale("pt", "BR"));
        InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reports/movementReport/MovementPlan.jasper");
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(inputStream, extractParams);
        return JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
        }catch (JRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new MarineException("ERROR", "Relatório", "Erro ao gerar plano de movimentação");
        }
```

This is my jrxml: [I used DontPad because its too long](http://dontpad.com/my-jrxml-jasper-file)

Comment: Please, post your jrxml

Answer (score 0):

Just found out, since I'm already bringing the data, not the JasperSoft queryng it, I need to pass and empty DataSource, so it works just fine:

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(inputStream, extractParams, new JREmptyDataSource());
```